# How do i open a webpage in vb6

Tags: vb6

How do i open a webpage in vb6.... inside the window frame ??

(i hope the question is clear and it is program related...sad my 1st 2 posts were closed so soon)

Thanks in advance -subanki

Comment: when i add the micrsoft internet controls (component ).......i am getting the error "File not found 'C:\Windows\sytem32\ieframe.dll\1'".... is thsi prob due to my vb6 or sp3 or i did something wrong.

Comment: This is the answer from a dude from the website mentioned by adatapost.....and it works for me too



In IE7, they have separated the library and code for the browser out of ieframe.dll. In the project references, I changed the reference for "Microsoft Internet Controls" from the ieframe.dll to shdocvw.ocx (browse for it in the same folder), saved my project, reopened it, and no longer received the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234651%28VS.80%29.aspx) article.
**Steps**

1. Start Visual Basic and create a new
   Standard project.
2. From the Project menu, select
   Components to open the Components
   dialog box. In the Components dialog
   box, add references to the
   Microsoft Internet Controls. Click
   OK to add the items to the toolbox.
3. Add an instance of the WebBrowser
   control, CommonDialog control, and a
   CommandButton to Form1.

Comment: oh like u dude , u r the first person who gave me complete and gud answer, thanks * 9999

Comment: ok as u said in the component window, in the controls tab, i selected Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (sp3) and Microsoft Internet Controls. and i unchecked selected items only. but i am getting the error "File not found 'C:\Windows\sytem32\ieframe.dll\1'".... is thsi prob due to my vb6 or sp3 or i did something wrong.

Comment: friend i am still getting this error "File not found 'C:\Windows\sytem32\ieframe.dll\1'"

Comment: Please read this thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/21935021-1dc7-445b-a829-b02489009aab

Comment: wat should i do next to open the C:/file1.html

Answer (score 0):

Just drop in a web browser component and then use it's Navigate method.

Comment: thanks for replying Mr. Christian Sciberras, how do i put a web browser component in my frame (do i need to answer this in a another post.)  can u porvide a simple code ..so that i can undertsand clearly. just started learning 3 days ago . so sorry for asking silly questions.